# Postgres : Change current user to root

Tags: macos, postgresql

Complete database newbie here. I installed postgres on my laptop to run some local apps and stuff. However the fact that postgres is setup using `myname` instead of `root` is quite a hinderance. Any way I cant replace it with `root`?

I open `psql` with this:

`psql -h localhost`

```
myname=# \l
                                         List of databases
     Name     |    Owner     | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |       Access privileges
--------------+--------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------
 myname       | myname | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 pixelmanager | myname | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 postgres     | myname | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 template0    | myname | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/myname              +
              |        |          |             |             | myname=CTc/myname
 template1    | myname | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/myname              +
              |        |          |             |             | myname=CTc/myname
(5 rows)
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE name OWNER TO { new_owner | CURRENT_USER | SESSION_USER }` [ALTER DATABASE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-alterdatabase.html) ?

Comment: I want it to be for all databases and not just 1. How would I do that?

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE myname ...`, `ALTER DATABASE pixelmanager ...` and so on. I not sure that is it possible to alter all databases simultaneously by single query. BTW I don't know about OSX, but on Linux databases initially owned by user `postgres`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the two default databases (`template1` / `template0`) to the user you want, and all future / new databases would be created with this new user.

For e.g.

```
ALTER DATABASE template0 OWNER TO newname1;
ALTER DATABASE template1 OWNER TO newname1;
```